# Crossdomain IFRAME with PDF document in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have an iframe that displays a PDF document in an sub  iframe of it.

This works in Chrome and Firefox when the root page and all of the frames are coming from the same domain.

This does not work in Chrome when the root page is coming from another domain ("Request blocked by Chrome" when reading the PDF). It is still working in Firefox in this case.

How can I make it work in Chrome?

.

Comment: The alternative I use is pdf.js (via react-pdf). It is needed for mobile anyway.  But it is of course another big download.